# Random Forest In Python [Error in r2_score]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am new to Machine Learning and to Python. I am trying to build a Random Forest model in order to predict cement strength.
There are two `.csv` files: `train_data.csv` and `test_data.csv`.

This is what I have done. I am trying to predict the `r2_score` here.

```
df=pd.read_csv("train_data(1).csv")
X=df.drop('strength',axis=1)
y=df['strength']
model=RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X,y)
X_test=pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
acc_R=metrics.r2_score(y,y_pred)
acc_R
```

The problem here is that the shape of `y` and `y_pred` is different. So I get this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [721, 309]
```

How do I correct this? Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `y_pred` with `y_test`. Not `y` which you used to train the model:

```
acc_R=metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

There should be another list of labels for the y_test in test_data.csv.

Try the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv("train_data(1).csv")
X=df.drop('strength',axis=1)
y=df['strength']
model=RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X,y)
df1=pd.read_csv("test_data.csv") # we read the csv data from test
X_test=df1.drop('strength',axis=1) # get the fields that we will predict
y_test=df1['strength'] # get the correct labels for X_test
y_pred=model.predict(X_test) # get the predicted results
acc_R=metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_pred) # compare
acc_R
```

Comment: The train.csv has 9 columns including strength, while the test.csv data has only 8 columns excluding the strength. So what will y_test be then?

Comment: @Carol, I updated my answer with comments. This should help you to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("train_data(1).csv")
X_train = df.drop('strength',axis=1)
y_train = df['strength']
model=RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
df_test = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
X_test = df.drop('strength',axis=1) # if your test data consists of 'strength' 
y_test = df['strength'] # if your test data consists of 'strength' 
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
acc_R = metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_pred)
acc_R
```

Comment: What if my test data does not have strength? How can I calculate the score and rms then?

Comment: You can,t. you need to compare your predicted data with something (in your case y_test). during training and testing process you should have these data in your dataset. When you are happy with your model and its ready to be deployed then you can only use the X_train data as input.